# Jquery multiple checkbox if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html file which contains a form, jquery and javascript. When i click a checkbox i want the form-background go larger. I have 3 checkboxes, so

when nr.1 is checked and nr.2 and nr.3 not, i want the form-bg to be 1500px height,

when nr.1 and nr.2 are checked and nr.3 not i want it to be 2000px height

and nr.1, nr.2 and nr.3 checked 2500px;

BUT when nr.2 and nr.3 are checked and i also want it to be 2000px.

I created this for testing when they are all checked, but it wont work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (($(".check_aan").is(':checked')) || ($(".check_ver").is(':checked')) || ($(".check_toe").is(':checked'))) {
        $(".form-bg").css("height", "2500px");
    } else {
        $(".form-bg").css("height", "4000px");
    }
});
```

.check_aan, .check_ver and .check_toe are the checkboxes.

I also tried '&&'      ','     'and'

Thanks.

Comment: You are performing the test only once when the page is loaded. Shouldn't you listen to the click or change events of the checkboxes?

Comment: @Shovalt yes it has to be, but how? Cause when i click 1 it has to be 1500px click 2 1500px, click 3 1500.px. But how do i have to do it with multiple clicks?

Comment: I haven't tested the function itself, I'm just saying that even if the function works, checking a checkbox won't call it. For the function to be called you need to change: $(document).ready(function()... to $(".check_aan,.check_ver,.check_toe").click(function() {...

Comment: Aah oke, thats problem nr 1 then, but now the next haha....

Comment: Also, I assume that what you actually want is to check how many checkboxes are checked, and decide the width accordingly.

Comment: how many, yes but not the width. That should always be the same.  In php i created a code to mail everything, there i mentioned all the possible combinations and typed the action behind it.

Comment: after check_aan the form shows more questions and checkboxes. Thats why the form need te be larger when you click several checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, then what I have understood is the following:

1. When *either* of the checkboxes is `checked` then -: `height: 1500px`.
2. When any *two* of the checkboxes are `checked` then -: `height: 2000px`.
3. When all the *three* checkboxes are `checked` then -: `height: 2500px`.
4. When *none* of the checkboxes is `checked` then -: `height` is not defined.

Based on this, refer to the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/66un96nc/) (*only the logic*) that I have created.

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check1" /> Checkbox 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check2" /> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check3" /> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
<p>

</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var isCheck1Checked = $('.check1').prop('checked');
    var isCheck2Checked = $('.check2').prop('checked');
    var isCheck3Checked = $('.check3').prop('checked');
    var text;
    if (!isCheck1Checked && !isCheck2Checked && !isCheck3Checked) {
      text = '';
    } else if (isCheck1Checked && isCheck2Checked && isCheck3Checked) {
      text = "The height is 2500px";
    } else if ((isCheck1Checked && isCheck2Checked) || (isCheck2Checked && isCheck3Checked) || (isCheck1Checked && isCheck3Checked) && !(isCheck1Checked && isCheck2Checked && isCheck3Checked)) {
      text = "The height is 2000px";
    } else {
      text = "The height is 1500px";
    }
    $('p').text(text);
  });
});
```

> **Update** : As per request

I have modified the code, which works well on `check` of every `checkbox`, it *increments* a certain value when *one*, *two* and *three* `checkboxes` are `checked`, but the *decrement*.

Refer the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/h9zydy7z/).

Code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check1" /> Checkbox 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check2" /> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check3" /> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>

<br />
<div class="target"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var isCheck1Checked = $('.check1').prop('checked');
    var isCheck2Checked = $('.check2').prop('checked');
    var isCheck3Checked = $('.check3').prop('checked');
    var text, c = 0;
    if (!isCheck1Checked && !isCheck2Checked && !isCheck3Checked) {
      text = '';
    } else if (isCheck1Checked && isCheck2Checked && isCheck3Checked) {
      text = "The height is 2500px";
      c = 300;
    } else if ((isCheck1Checked && isCheck2Checked) || (isCheck2Checked && isCheck3Checked) || (isCheck1Checked && isCheck3Checked) && !(    isCheck1Checked && isCheck2Checked && isCheck3Checked)) {
      text = "The height is 2000px";
      c = 200;
    } else {
      text = "The height is 1500px";
      c = 50;
    }

    var oldHeight = parseInt($('.target').css('height'));
    $('.target').css('height', oldHeight + c + 'px');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks. This helps me a lot. now i have an other question, it it with this way also possible to count the form-bg up with 200? So, when check 1 and check 2 is checked then bg + 200 px?

Comment: u mean to say that one should be able to increment the `height` by `200px` on `check` of more than one `checkbox`. Right?

Comment: yeah, if that is possible? that would me more easy i think? so when you check nr1 increment the height by 200 and nr2 by 300 or something?

Comment: I have added an update in the post, please refer to it.

Comment: thats again helps alot, but when it is checked, and after that unchecked, they don't get smaller?

Comment: ofcourse, I mentioned the same in the updated post, that it works only for increment and not *decrement*.